# Oracle database connection via Java

Tags: java, database, oracle, prepared-statement

I have a basic connection to an oracle database, I getting back the first two print statements i.e connecting to the database and reading back the query which is to be inserted but I'm not reaching line `updateQuery = statement.executeUpdate();` and therefore the statement isn't executed.

I'm getting no error and I have the ojdbc driver downloaded, any suggestions ?

```
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class conn1 {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        //Scanner out = new Scanner(String);
        //In Java, we use plain JDBC calls to insert a record in STUDENTS table. We use sequence STUDENT_SEQ to generate primary key. 
        //Once the record is inserted, we want the last inserted primary value.

        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        int updateQuery = 0;
        String QUERY = "INSERT INTO SYS.STUDENTS (student_id, NAME, EMAIL, BIRTH_DATE)"
                + "VALUES ('1','Hermoine', 'Hermoine@hogwarts.edu', '08-Nov-1987')";

        // load oracle driver
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // get database connection from connection string
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:attendanced", "louise", "Attend123!");
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("Successfullly connected to Oracle DB");

            try {
                statement = connection.prepareStatement(QUERY);
                System.out.println("Insert This Query :" + QUERY);
                updateQuery = statement.executeUpdate();   //Erroneous line.

                if (updateQuery != 0) {
                    System.out.println("Record inserted successfully");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error, Record not inserted");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to connect to Oracle DB");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did u get any stack trace?

Comment: You should be seeing a stack trace of a SQLException from the `executeUpdate()`; not obvious why you wouldn't, but you could try re-throwing it as a RuntimeException maybe. Maybe you're running it from an IDE which is sending that output somewhere unexpected? Anyway, as a guess, either it doesn't like you passing a string instead of a date (use `to_date()` to explicitly set the format model); or the table is not in the `SYS` schema (I hope it isn't, that's a bad idea) or your `louise` user doesn't have privileges on it. You need to figure out why the exception isn't being shown anyway.

Comment: Or your could be getting a constraint violation, since you're using a fixed value for the key instead of using the sequence. But when you say it isn't reaching the `executeUpdate()`, do you mean it's stopping without further output, or that it appears to hang? If it's hanging then you might have uncommitted data in another session and it's blocking waiting for that to commit/rollback.

Comment: im not getting a stack trace its just hanging

Comment: i have all privileges for user louise and the table is in SYS schema, i dont have a problem connecting to the database and its finding the table but its not inserting the data

Comment: Because you do not set any parameters, then PreparedStatement is not neccessary. Try to call createStatement and then executeUpdate(QUERY).

Comment: Does it hang forever? It shall fail with timeout exception some time. Its description may be useful.

Comment: i tried create statement originally and i had the same problem so i moved to prepared statement. yes it hangs forever

Comment: Try something simple: do a select from your table. Doesn't matter whether there is anything there or not, just see if it runs it. That should eliminate a number of possibilities (e.g. there's a lock preventing the insert).

Comment: "*and the table is in SYS schema,*" Do ***NOT*** create your own tables in the `SYS` schema. Don't do that! Ever! And of course if the table is in the `SYS` schema, `louise` will not be able to access it.

Comment: Try to execute the same statement in some oracle client and see if its inserting.

Comment: If it's hanging then you almost certainly have uncommitted data in another session. Did you try to do the insert manually in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer etc. before trying it from Java? If so find that session, commit or rollback, and try the Java version again.

Comment: i went back to create statement statement and used a boolean , its working fine now. Also FYI even though the table is in the SYS schema user louise CAN access it.   connection.createStatement();
    

    System.out.println("Insert Record Query :"+QUERY);

    boolean returnValue = statement.execute(QUERY);

Comment: @user3168352 - creating your own tables in the `SYS` schema is still a bad idea, even if you can access them. You should never touch that schema. Why wasn't the table created in the `LOUISE` schema instead? Anyway... [`execute` returns boolean, `executeUpdate` returns int](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html), so that doesn't really explain why it wasn't working before.